# USB keyboard LEDs turn on for a few seconds when PC is off

Tags: keyboard, desktop-computer

Usually, when I turn off my PC the keyboard LEDs would stay off. But for the past day every now and again, the LEDs on my USB keyboard turn on for a few seconds when the PC is off.

Why is that? Should I worry?

Comment: Is it USB keyboard? or PS/2?

Comment: Usb keyboard, today is the first time it has started doing that

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I have put that information in your question (as you could by [editing](http://superuser.com/posts/1135355/edit)) where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably connected your keyboard to a powered USB port (commonly has a small lightning icon near the port, but not always). A powered port allows USB devices to charge when the computer is off. Your keyboard is probably drawing power from your computer's battery. Try connecting to a different USB port.

Comment: Ok, i will try, but yesterday is the first time it happened